# How to make active Links in Next.JS using styled-components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I was making a simple navbar in a side project and faced a problem with active links in Next.JS, in react you could just use react-router-dom that has a Link component with a activeclass atribute, but not in Next.JS (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work I used the `UseRouter` `UseState` hooks

```
const router = useRouter();
const [pathName, setPathName] = useState(router.pathname);
```

router.pathname is getting whatever `/[route]` is currently on your url.

```
const newPathName = () => {
    setPathName(router.pathname);
  };

<Link href="/" passHref>
       <StyledLink onClick={newPathName} pathname={pathName}>
         Home
       </StyledLink>
</Link>
```

And by using it as a onClick function, it sets the useState to a new route

StyledLink would be the styled component that is going to change colors when clicked

```
export const StyledLink = styled.a`
  color: ${(props) => (props.href === props.pathname ? "#a37600" : "#eaaa00")};
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  :hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #a37600;
  }
`;
```

I basically did this answer because I was searching about this for 30min or so and didn't find anything simple and actually fast enough for a navbar, if there was a similar or simpler answer please link it to me.

Comment: I find that I have to double click to have the color change. Did you find this as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this just by using `useRouter` without using `useState` (seeing as `setState` is asynchronous, you would rather use something that doesn't rely on this).

```
  import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
  ...
  const router = useRouter();
```

Your `Link` components would then look like this:

```
<Link href="/" passHref>
  <LinkText pathName={router.pathname}>Home</LinkText>
</Link>
```

Finally, your inner component (in my case, it's `LinkText`) would have this line:

```
export const LinkText = styled.a`
  color: ${(props) => (props.href === props.pathName ? #728c69 : #fff)};
`;
```